# Making model and animation for Unity using MakeHuman and Blender

Tags: animation, unity, makehuman

I'm learning Unity and trying to make a scene which need a model and some animations. I came up with using MakeHuman 1.1.1 and Blender 2.79b. I exported model from MakeHuman to .mhx file and import to Blender. But someone said that mhx rig wasn't compatible with Unity (i don't know if he were right). So i'm stucking. I want to know which is the best workflow to make animations of MakeHuman model in Blender for Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MakeHuman ships with the "Game Engine Rig", which is compatible with the mecanim unity functionality. The appropriate work flow is:

- Enable the game engine rig in makehuman (under pose -> skeleton)
- Export using mhx2
- In blender, either import without overrides or make sure to leave the rig as it is upon import

You only get the MHX rig if you explicitly ask for it when importing an MHX file in blender. Otherwise, the rig exported from MakeHuman will be used.

As an alternative to using MHX2, there is also a new pipeline for integrating MakeHuman and blender, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAwfR-G813g